# Проблемы с индексацией сайта Яндексом

Tags: seo, индексация, яндекс-поиск

Поисковая система Яндекс проиндексировала мой сайт, загрузила все страницы, но в поиск вывела только одну. Спрашивал в службе поддержки причины, но ничего вразумительного так и не получил. Может, кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 2):

Подозреваю что ТП Яндекса ответила что-то в том духе что остальные страницы появятся в выдаче позже. И скорее всего это именно так. В этом отношении Яндекс довольно-таки медлителен. При-чём «позже» может оказаться достаточно ощутимым сроком, порядка нескольких недель. Впрочем мой опыт в этом отношении явно недостаточен что-бы делать прогнозы.

Возможно получится несколько ускорить дело создав xml карту сайта и скормив её поисковикам. Для популярных CMS есть готовые инструменты генерации таких карт. Ключевые слова для поиска "xml sitemap".

Comment: Как-то я не посмотрел на дату. Ну вдруг ещё актуально, или кому-то другому пригодится.